# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

Tags: angular, database, firebase

I want to update data in firebase(realtime database), by passing the table values in update form,but it shows me an error =

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

and whenever I try to use `[(ngModel)]="product.price"` my code show the error

> Cannot read property 'price' of null

**This is my .ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/services/category.service';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  product: any = {};
  categories$;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductsService
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id)
      this.productService.get(id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(p => this.product = p);

  }
  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    console.log(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

**This is my .html file**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="86%">
      <mat-grid-tile>
            <form class="example-form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
                  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label for="title">Product Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" type="text" id="title" required
                              #pname="ngModel">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="pname.touched"></mat-error>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <mat-form-field class="mywidth" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label for="price">Product Price</mat-label>
                        <input matInput ngModel name="price" type="number" id="price" #pprice="ngModel" required
                              [min]="0">
                        <mat-error style="color: red;" *ngIf="pprice.touched && pprice.invalid">field required*
                        </mat-error>
                        <span mat-button matSuffix mat-stroked-button aria-label="search">
                              <mat-icon>₹</mat-icon>
                        </span>
                  </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                  <mat-radio-group ngModel name="subprice" #subprice="ngModel">
                        <mat-radio-button value="kg">/kg</mat-radio-button>&nbsp;
                        <mat-radio-button value="g">/g</mat-radio-button>&nbsp;
                        <mat-radio-button value="liter">/liter</mat-radio-button>
                  </mat-radio-group>
                  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
                        <mat-select ngModel name="category" id="category" required #cat="ngModel">
                              <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                              <mat-option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.name">{{ c.name }}
                              </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                        <mat-error style="color: red;" *ngIf="cat.touched && cat.invalid">field required*</mat-error>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label for="imageUrl">ImageUrl</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" ngModel name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" #imgUrl="ngModel">
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="warn">Save</button>
            </form>
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-card class="example-card">
                  <mat-card-header>
                        <mat-card-title>{{ pname.value }}</mat-card-title>
                  </mat-card-header>
                  <img mat-card-image [src]="imgUrl.value">
                  <mat-card-content>
                        <p>{{ pprice.value }} / {{ subprice.value }}</p>
                  </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>

      </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

**This is my product.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
    import { Item } from '../models/product';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ProductsService {
      constructor(
        private db: AngularFireDatabase
      ) { }

      create(product) {
        return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
      }
      getAll() {
        return this.db.list('/products').valueChanges();
      }
      get(productId) {
        return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).valueChanges();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some steps to be taken:
1. create an interface and declare all input parameters: product.ts

```
   export interface Product {
      key?: string;
      title: string;
      price: number;
      etc...
}
```

2. in product.service.ts:

   getAll() {
       return this.db.list('/products/')
             .snapshotChanges()
             .pipe(
               map(actions =>
                 actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.key, ...(a.payload.val() as {}) }))
               )
             );
     }
3. in my.ts, declare d and replace let id and if() as below:

   id;
         this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
           if (this.id)
             this.productService.get(this.id)
               .subscribe(p => this.product = p);

4.try it

Answer (score 1):

`this.product` is assigned inside the subscription, but when the templates is rendered it's still undefined, you should use the async pipe when accessing observables value inside the template or wrap the used of `product.title` with ngIf on the product object.

Comment: i already use async pipe  in .html file, which is for displaying firebase data in tabular form

Comment: You don't, here is your problem `[(ngModel)]="product.title"`, you use product object before you set him.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `take(1)`. Not sure but I think the first value of the observable might be undefined. Try `takeuntil`, but I also recommend to not use subscribe, use async pipe instead

Comment: can you please justify your reply